# Scaling KAFKA to manage higher TPS using a synchronic request/reply configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, openshift

I am new to KAFKA and I am working on a POC to migrate our  current ESB into microservices. Our current ESB work using SOAP services so I need to keep using the request/reply paradigm.

The POC consist on a spring boot microservice. One instance of the application is the producer using the following code:

```
@Endpoint
public class AcctInfoSoapServiceController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AcctInfoSoapServiceController.class);

    @Autowired
    KafkaAsyncService kafkaAsyncService;


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://firstbankpr.com/feis/common/model", localPart = "GetAccountInfoRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetAccountInfoResponse getModelResponse(@RequestPayload GetAccountInfoRequest accountInfo) throws Exception {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        LOGGER.info("Returning request for account " + accountInfo.getInGetAccountInfo().getAccountNumber() );

        AccountInquiryDto modelResponse = kafkaAsyncService.getModelResponse(accountInfo.getInGetAccountInfo());

        GetAccountInfoResponse response = ObjectFactory.getGetAccountInfoResponse(modelResponse);

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        LOGGER.info("Returning request in " + elapsedTime + " ms  for account = "  + accountInfo.getInGetAccountInfo().getAccountNumber() + "  " +  response );

        return response;

    }

}


public AccountInquiryDto getModelResponse(InGetAccountInfo accountInfo) throws Exception{

        LOGGER.info("Received request for request  for account " + accountInfo);

        // create producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, InGetAccountInfo> record = new ProducerRecord<String, InGetAccountInfo>(requestTopic,accountInfo);
        // set reply topic in header
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));

        // post in kafka topic
        RequestReplyFuture<String, InGetAccountInfo, AccountInquiryDto> sendAndReceive = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);

        // confirm if producer produced successfully
        SendResult<String, InGetAccountInfo> sendResult = sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get();

       // //print all headers
        sendResult.getProducerRecord().headers().forEach(header -> System.out.println(header.key() + ":" + header.value().toString()));

        // get consumer record
        ConsumerRecord<String, AccountInquiryDto> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        AccountInquiryDto modelResponse = mapper.convertValue(
                consumerRecord.value(),
                new TypeReference<AccountInquiryDto>() { });


        LOGGER.info("Returning record for " + modelResponse);

        return modelResponse;

    }
```

The following is the configuration of the producer

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        //props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId +  "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId +  "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        //props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
       // props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        //props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        //props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId +  "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,"2");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, InGetAccountInfo, AccountInquiryDto> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> pf, KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, AccountInquiryDto> container){
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate(pf, container);

    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> requestProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyConsumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<AccountInquiryDto> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages(InGetAccountInfo.class.getPackage().getName());
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages(AccountInquiryDto.class.getPackage().getName());
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),jsonDeserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, AccountInquiryDto> cf) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
        return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
    }



    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin admin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }



    @Bean
    public KafkaAsyncService kafkaAsyncService(){
        return new KafkaAsyncService();
    }
```

I have one instance of the spring boot application working as the KAFKA consumer with the following code:

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}", containerFactory = "requestReplyListenerContainerFactory")
  @SendTo
  public Message<?> listenPartition0(InGetAccountInfo accountInfo,
                                     @Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) byte[] replyTo,
                                     @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int id) {

    try {

      LOGGER.info("Received request for partition id = " +  id);
      LOGGER.info("Received request for accountInfo = " +  accountInfo.getAccountNumber());

      AccountInquiryDto accountInfoDto  = getAccountInquiryDto(accountInfo);

      LOGGER.info("Returning accountInfoDto = " +  accountInfoDto.toString());

      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountInfoDto)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, replyTo)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, id)
              .build();


    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.toString(),e);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

The following is the configuration of the consumer

```
 @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    //props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId +  "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId +  "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId +  "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,"2");
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> requestConsumerFactory() {
    JsonDeserializer<InGetAccountInfo> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages(InGetAccountInfo.class.getPackage().getName());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),jsonDeserializer);
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, InGetAccountInfo>> requestReplyListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, InGetAccountInfo> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(requestConsumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.setReplyTemplate(replyTemplate());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyProducerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, AccountInquiryDto> replyTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(replyProducerFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public DepAcctInqConsumerController Controller() {
    return new DepAcctInqConsumerController();
  }
  @Bean

  public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
  }

  @Bean
  public NewTopic requestTopic() {
    Map<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put("retention.ms", replyTimeout.toString());
    return new NewTopic(requestTopic, 2, (short) 2).configs(configs);
  }
```

KAFKA is using one topic with 5 partitions. When I run a load test using SoapUI I get about 19 TPS using 20 threads. The TPS remain the same even when I increment the number of partitions to 10 using 20 threads, incrementing the number of threads to 40 does not increment the TPS even if the number of partitions is higher (up to 10). Also incrementing the number of instances for a consumer and a producer to 2 and configuring a Load balancer to distribute the load does not change the TPS (which remains in about 20). In this case it seems that KAFKA is the bottleneck.

The only way I was able to increment the TPS was by assigning a different topic to each instance of the consumer/producer pair. When using the load balancer The TPS incremented to 38 TPS which is about double what I obtained with one instance of the consumer/producer pair. Monitoring  the servers running the spring boot application does not provide any meaningful information since the CPU load and memory remains very low. The KAFKA servers also remains low on usage with about 20% CPU utilization. Currently kafka is using only one broker.

I am looking for advice on how to configure KAFKA so that I can increase the number of instances of the spring boot application using the same topic, this will allow me to increase the TPS with every new instance of the consumer/producer that starts. I understand that with every new instance  of the consumer/producer I may need to increment the number of partitions on a topic.  The final goal is to run these as PODS inside an openshift cluster where the application should be able to automatically grow when traffic increases.

Comment: This depends on a great many configurations, can you please add the consumer and producer configuration on both sides? How many brokers do you have in your Kafka cluster? What is TPS, transactions per second?

Comment: Partitions is the limit on parallel reads and writes, it's hard to prescribe a number though. As long as you have more partitions than brokers and the leaders are spread over the brokers nicely you should get good throughput.   At my work we usually go for a multiple of the number of brokers to allow even distribution but we rarely need to increase partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added the information requested on the main post

Comment: Thank you! Also, an unsolicited opinion, sorry about this: Once you are in Openshift you will be able to make scalable services, accessible using something like HTTP or gRPC or HTTP/2 for request/response. I love Kafka but request-response over kafka is maybe fighting against the tool. I've found Kafka really strong for reliably producing large quantities of data that is to be read, asynchronously, by multiple downstream apps. Request-response requires something odd like dedicated response topic per client, or correlation ids in the response.

Comment: I'd try isolating different parts of the workload, how fast can you push to the `request` topic without waiting on the reply? Also, the kafka distribution comes with a load testing client you could try for a second data source. ```~/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin $ ./kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --help```

Comment: Your configs look fine, the default settings of the clients are good if you want low latency. 0 `linger.ms` on producers, 1 `fetch.min.bytes` on the consumers. You should be producing and consuming without delays.

Comment: TPS stands for Transactions per second.

Comment: What is KafkaAsyncService doing? How does it implement waiting for the message?

Comment: You can see the method from the KafkaAsyncService class  above and it is called getModelResponse. where the producer waits for the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233769/discussion-between-roby-and-gabriel-duchateau).